# index array checkbox not functioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

The checkbox that is created next to the task can not be set to the checked position, which would create a line across the task. When opening console I don't get any errors, only the following error:

> A form field element has neither an id nor a name attribute

When clicking on the checkbox increments up.
I don't know how to assign a name or attribute to the checkbox, as this is what I assume the problem is.

This is the function that would create the list items with checkboxes:
and the CSS class that crosses off the listed item.

```js
let tasks = [];

function addTask() {
    const taskInput = document.getElementById("addTaskInput");
    const taskText = taskInput.value.trim();
    if (taskText !== "") {
        tasks.push({ text: taskText, completed: false });
        renderTasks();
        taskInput.value = "";
    }
}

function toggleTask(index) {
    tasks[index].complete = !tasks[index].completed;
    renderTasks();
}

function deleteTask(index) {
    tasks.splice(index, 1);
    renderTasks();
}

function renderTasks () {
    const taskList = document.getElementById("added-task")
    taskList.innerHTML = "";
    tasks.forEach((task, index) => {
        const li = document.createElement("li");
        const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.checked = task.completed;
        checkbox.addEventListener("change", () => toggleTask(index));
        li.appendChild(checkbox);

        const taskText = document.createElement("span");
        taskText.textContent = task.text;
        taskText.className = "task" + (task.completed ? " complete " : "");
        li.appendChild(taskText);

        const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
        deleteBtn.textContent = "Delete";
        deleteBtn.className = "delete-btn"
        deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => deleteTask(index));
        li.appendChild(deleteBtn);

        taskList.appendChild(li);
    });
}
```

```css
.task.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="title">To Do List</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="addTaskInput" placeholder="Add Task">
        <button class="add-task-btn" onclick="addTask()">Add Task</button>
        <ul id="added-task"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the `toogleTask` method because it's where the issue lies - when the user clicks on a checkbox.

Comment: As for assigning a name or an id to a checkbox, just do (when creating it): `checkbox.name = 'chk' + index;` or `checkbox.name = 'chk+ index;`

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please click [edit], scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and produce a [mcve] - your example does not add the LI to the task list either

Comment: Also I strongly suggest you delegate the click from the added-tasks.

Comment: I edit the code above to include all of the functions, which includes toggleTask that Rickard had requested.

Answer (score 1):

Since your code is a bit incomplete, I tried to improvise and re-wrtitten it in bare minimal form.

```js
let tasks = [];
function renderTasks () {
    const taskList = document.getElementById("added-task")
    taskList.innerHTML = "";
    tasks.forEach((task, index) => {
        const li = document.createElement("li");
        const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
        const label = document.createElement("label");
        label.for = "chk_"+index
        label.innerText = task.value
        task.completed ? li.classList.add("completed") : ""
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.name = "chk_"+index
        checkbox.value = task.name;
        checkbox.checked = task.completed;
        checkbox.addEventListener("change",()=>toggleTask(index));
        li.appendChild(checkbox);
        li.appendChild(label);
        taskList.appendChild(li);
    });
  }

function addTask() {
  let name = document.getElementById("addTaskInput");
  console.log(name);
  tasks.push({value: name.value, completed: false});
  name.value = "";
  renderTasks();
}

function toggleTask(index) {
  tasks[index].completed = !tasks[index].completed;
  renderTasks();
}
```

```css
.completed {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="addTaskInput" placeholder="Add Task">
    <button class="add-task-btn" onclick="addTask()">Add Task</button>
    <ul id="added-task"></ul>
</div>
```

You can add validation is addTask method to check unique task names, input length etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your are facing error not due to checkbox but due to handling `<input>` and `<button>`. I have formatted this code below as per your requirement.

Please let me know if it works for you :

```js
const tasks = []; // Here we are storing the tasks

function addTask() {
    const taskInput = document.getElementById("addTaskInput");
    const taskText = taskInput.value.trim();
    if (taskText !== "") {
        tasks.push({ text: taskText, completed: false });
        renderTasks();
        taskInput.value = ""; // Clear input after adding task
    }
}

function toggleTask(index) {
    tasks[index].completed = !tasks[index].completed;
    renderTasks();
}

function renderTasks() {
    const taskList = document.getElementById("added-task");
    taskList.innerHTML = "";
    tasks.forEach((task, index) => {
        const li = document.createElement("li");
        const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.checked = task.completed;
        checkbox.addEventListener("change", () => toggleTask(index));
        li.appendChild(checkbox);
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task.text));
        if (task.completed) {
            li.classList.add("completed");
        }
        taskList.appendChild(li);
    });
}
```

```css
.task.completed {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="addTaskInput" placeholder="Add Task">
  <button class="add-task-btn" onclick="addTask()">Add Task</button>
  <ul id="added-task"></ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: The amendment does not fix the issue, The text that appears in the list section is doubled.